# PyWinAuto - How do I check when a button control becomes visible?

Tags: python, button, ui-automation, pywinauto

I am writing UI Automation tests for a WPF application that has a button which only becomes enabled on the UI when certain conditions are met.

I've read through all the uia_controls wrappers available to use (https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.controls.uia_controls.html) and there doesn't seem to be one that will allow me to check whether a button control is enabled before clicking on it.

Please advise if pywinauto is able to check that a button is enabled before interacting with it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the enabled property of the element_info.

https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.element_info.html#pywinauto.element_info.ElementInfo.enabled

Comment: Thanks, it seems the enabled property for element_info hasn't been implemented. The "enabled" property only raises the NotImplementedError() exception. The pywinauto.uia_element_info has the enabled property as well and there is code to check whether the element is enabled. However I am having trouble initialising the UIAElementInfo class to access that property. It is returning "TypeError: UIAElementInfo object can be initialized with integer or IUIAutomationElement instance only!"

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways. The first one is calling `.wait('visible', timeout=10)` on WindowSpecification object. The second one is checking return result of method `.is_visible()` for the wrapper object. Of course, you should know the difference between WindowSpecification and wrapper (see [the Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)).

Also see chapter [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html).

P.S. Using `UIAElementInfo` directly is not recommended as it is low level of the implementation hidden behind wrapper interface.